# No module named 'grpc_status' error in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, grpc-python

I am trying to connect to my Spark cluster using Pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://localhost").getOrCreate()
```

But I get a ModuleNotFoundEroor saying:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grpc_status'`

I already installed grpcio and grpcio-tools . There seems to be no module called grpc-status available for pip installation. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```bash
pip install grpcio-status
```

Also see: https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-status/

Comment: Already did it. Still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to make sure that your PySpark use the same python kernel as the one you installed `grpcio-status`. You should check / set the enviornment viaraible `PYSPARK_PYTHON` or Spark config `spark.pyspark.python`. Or you can simply run python (without spark) and try `import grpc_status` to check it out.